# Overriding Chef Attributes In Role File

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm trying to override https://github.com/elasticsearch/cookbook-elasticsearch/blob/master/attributes/default.rb#L51 with a block like http://pastie.org/private/rfrpsjvl2ldxjky91r6zqg using Chef Solo.

```
# filename: chef/roles/elasticsearch.rb
name "elasticsearch"
description "Args"
run_list ['recipe[java]', 'recipe[elasticsearch]']
override_attributes { "node" => { "elasticsearch" => { "bootstrap" => {  "mlockall" => false } } } }
# Also tried:
# override_attributes { "elasticsearch" => { "bootstrap" => {  "mlockall" => false } } }
```

It seems like this may have been a bug in my chef version(`11.4.4`, [issue at Google Cache, because of the opscodepocalypse](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aRxyeriaNzksJ%3atickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4319+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de))

It appears to be some issue with recently introduced changed to requiring additional metadata, but I can't find any reference to that.

Without defining a wrapper cookbook, how can I override these attributes?

Bonus if anyone can tell me how I could debug this myself with Chef-solo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to make this work at all, I resorted to writing the following in my `site-cookbooks/base/attributes/default.rb`:

```
override.elasticsearch[:bootstrap][:mlockall] = false
```

It appears that the Chef 11 attribute resolution precedences changed quite a lot: http://www.opscode.com/blog/2013/02/05/chef-11-in-depth-attributes-changes/.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
override_attributes :elasticsearch => { :bootstrap => {  :mlockall => false } }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, apparently it's not a question of symbols vs. strings. :(

Comment: Do you have something in the `elasticsearch`, `settings`, data bag item? On line #11, it overrides the attributes with this. Btw this is probably a way to override the attribute you want as well.

Comment: Unfortunately not, there's no data bags.

Comment: But you could override the settings using a data bag as per the code. See [Chef Solo](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_solo.html) for info. Basically `mkdir -p /var/chef-solo/data_bags/elasticsearch`, then create a `settings.json` in this directory. In the JSON document, add an entry for each node environment with the settings you want to override. The `id` of the JSON doc should be `settings`.